# Magento 2 : My billing and shipping address the same checkbox is auto uncheck after reload payment block

Tags: magento2

In Checkout page , 
Magento 2 : 
`My billing and shipping address the same` checkbox is automatically uncheck while reload process payment block during ajax process.
[image]

Comment: can you specify your issue in detail.

Comment: Please check this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/gwhq6w
i mean this check box is unchecked on load payment block

Comment: can you also provide screen-sort which show issues?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gwi20g
it will not pulling all address record from shipping adress

Comment: Have you solved this error? I'm also struck in same error.